# How can i make sending e-mail via ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I cannot make sending to email via ajax with sending variable. Could you help me or correct this code. I need after clicking button "send letter" it forms string from list of goods and after it pass it to php to send by e-mail.

js code here

```
  function cancelClicked() {
        var parseData = sessionStorage.getItem("parseData");// "Имя: "+$('input').attr('name').value+"\n"+"Телефон: "+$('input').attr('phone').value+"\n"+"Почта: "+$('input').attr('email').value;
        $('.t-two ul li').each(function(){
            var name = $(this).text();
            var qnt = $(this).find('b').text();
            var total = parseInt($(this).find('p').text())*parseInt(qnt);
            parseData += "\n "+name+" Количество: "+"qnt"+" Цена: "+total;
            alert(parseData);
        });
    $.post("email.php", {
        parseData: parseData
    }, function(parseData) {
        if (parseData != "") {
            alert('We sent Jquery string to PHP : ' + parseData);
        }
    });

                // function below will run clear.php?h=michael
                /*$.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "email.php",
                data: {'parseData': parseData }
            });*/
    };
```

php code here

```
<?php
$to      = 'filatovsrg94@gmail.com';
$subject = 'ЗАКАЗ';
$message = 'e-mail: '.substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email'])), 0, 30)." ".
'Телефон: '.substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['phone'])), 0, 30)." ".
'Имя'.substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name'])), 0, 30)." "."Заказ ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['parseData']);

mail($to, $subject, $message);
?>
```

Comment: @PetervanderWal javascript does not require `;` Furthermore, what is the problem that you're encountering here? Also, please don't use the `mail()` function directly. Several providers require proper headers and building them from scratch is tiresome. Consider moving to the [PHPMailer Class](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: ($_POST['paeseData']) must be ($_POST['parseData']) I know
but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Sidenote: Missing semi-colon at the end of `"Заказ ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['paeseData'])` - `"Заказ ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['paeseData']);` <=

Comment: @Sidenote i noticed it before but nothing changes

Comment: You're sending to Gmail and you're missing headers that need to be passed along which is why it's not working. Please consider reading up on sending an email to gmail with PHP so you can garner further understanding.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it sends e-mail but without parseData

Comment: Dump the `parseData` on the server in an `exit()` command and check in the ajax success with `console.log(parseData);` wha'ts in it

Comment: @Ohgodwhy how can I do it?